# How to pass an array from module to template file?

Tags: 7, theming

I have an array printing in module file. I want to theme that array data,so I am not getting how can I get that array data in template file. I don't want to create theme function and all. is there any inline solution to pass from module to template. My code is like below.

```
$data['listfiles'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $filesheader,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
  );

  return $data;
```

I want to pass $data variable to the template file, so that I can theme the data.Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function YOURMODULE_theme() {
  $themes = array(
    'example' => array(
      'template' => 'templates/example',
      'arguments' => array('data' => NULL),
    ),
  );
  return $themes;
}
```

after this you can pass your data as

> return theme('example', array('data' => $data));

Refer [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x#comment-14989)

And if want to use preprocess to alter data, see [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x)

Answer (score 0):

[hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x). You can add your data like `$vars['my_data'] = $my_data` then access it using `$my_data` in the tpl.